# How to send oauth2.0 id_token in http header? Incorrect padding error

Tags: http, flask, oauth-2.0, http-headers

I'm trying to send a googleId and id_token in an http header. For some reason, I cannot verify the token due to an incorrect padding error.
I'm following this guide: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

I tried copying the id_token string into my code (replacing the variable request_user_id_token), and the verify_oauth2_token works just fine. There's a problem because I'm reading it off the http header.

I also printed the value of request_user_id_token and it is exactly the same as expected.

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():

try:
    request_user_id = request.headers.get('google-id')
    request_user_id_token = request.headers.get('google-id-token')

    if not (request_user_id and request_user_id_token):
        raise ValueError('Missing id and id token in request headers')


    # THIS LINE THROWS
    id_token.verify_oauth2_token(request_user_id_token, requests.Request(), os.environ.get("ELEVATE_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"))

    print(google_id_info)
    if google_id_info['iss'] not in ['accounts.google.com', 'https://accounts.google.com']:
        raise ValueError('Wrong issuer.')

    # ID token is valid. Get the user's Google Account ID from the decoded token.
    google_user_id = int(google_id_info['sub'])

    if request_user_id != google_user_id:
        raise ValueError('The supplied google id does not match the supplied id token')

# Authentication Error (Incliding Expired Token)
except ValueError as error:
    print(error)
    pass
```

Printing the error at the end just outputs 'Incorrect Padding'

Comment: 1) This usually means that you have whitespace (space, newline, etc.) before or after the token. In Python do this `token = token.strip()`. 2) Sometimes the base64 encoding is not padded correctly. Add three equal signs to the end `token += '==='`

Comment: If neither of those work, then make sure that the ID Token that you are passing to `verify_oauth2_token` matches what you originally sent. Another item, what is the third arg that you are calling `verify_oauth2_token` with? Normally that should be `audience=something`.